# Facebook Graph API Get All Events For Latitude and Longitude

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get All public events for given location. Here is what I'm using now

```
SELECT+name,+pic_cover,start_time,+end_time,+location,+description,venue++FROM+event+WHERE+eid++in(SELECT+eid+FROM+event_member+WHERE+uid+IN+(SELECT+page_id+FROM+place+WHERE+distance(latitude,+longitude,+"40.1811",+"44.5136")+<+50000+limit+0,15000))+ORDER+BY+start_time+desc+limit+0,1500
```

But there are huge count of events with that location which didn't returning with that FQL query. 
**Is there any chance to get all events for given location or it may be by City ?**
I'm using Python , but if you have some example code on any language please write it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you omit the subquery for the `event_member` table, you'll eventually get more results. Please consider that the results will only include Events created by the Page itself, not those created by individual users.

```
SELECT name, pic_cover,start_time, end_time, location, description,venue FROM event WHERE creator IN (SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "40.1811", "44.5136") < 50000 limit 0,15000) and start_time > now() ORDER BY start_time desc limit 0,1500
```

If you have a list of venues of interest, you could use the method I described here: [Facebook FQL find all events that take place at a certain venue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368629/facebook-fql-find-all-events-that-take-place-at-a-certain-venue/22373119#22373119)

**Edit 2017-12-20:**

As it is now impossible to use FQL if the app was created after 2014-04-30, a direct search is no longer possible. To achieve that, a three-step approach must be used, as implemented in https://github.com/tobilg/facebook-events-by-location-core for example.

Comment: Facebook is updating Graph API to 2.1 and FQL will not be available. Can anyone suggest how to request "nearby events" with Graph API?

Comment: As you can't use FQL, I assume that this is no longer possible because the Graph API itself has no way to search events by location IMHO: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#search