# Searching public events using graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am currently trying to learn about the graph api. From what I am getting in my research, I see that with V2.0 you can't public search anymore. I then found the following post:

[Facebook Graph API Get All Events For Latitude and Longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616846/facebook-graph-api-get-all-events-for-latitude-and-longitude/22630545#22630545)

I looks here as they are getting public events using location to filter the searches and this would be exectly what I would want to be doing. Can some one clear up if you can search public events that are part of facebook after the V2.0 update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cited answer is from me... Unfortunately, FQL is deprecated after v2.0, so you can't use this method anymore.

What you theorically could do is a two-step batch request, where you first query looks for pages in a certain radius around the lat/lng position, and then take these results as input for the second query for the page's events. Downside of this is that the second `/?ids=` request only takes 50 input ids.

Another solution would be to have the first request as standalone, and then take the id list from the first one and split the ids in batches of 50 and produce the batch request code in the application itself, and fire it then.

Sample code:

```
curl -k \
-F 'access_token={YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN}' \
-F 'include_headers=false' \
-F 'batch=[
  {
    "method":"GET",
    "name":"places",
    "relative_url":"search?type=place&center=37.780073,-122.408217&distance=1000&limit=50&fields=id",
  }, 
  {
    "method":"GET",
    "relative_url":"?ids={result=places:$.data.*.id}&fields=id,name,events"
  }
]' \
https://graph.facebook.com
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

There is a sample project which can search public events by location on GitHub:

- https://github.com/tobilg/facebook-events-by-location

Comment: Awesome answer! Much appreciated.