# Facebook API place distance

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

These days I have had the pleasure to play a little bit with the facebook api, but there are things that I can not understand. I'm searching for all the pages that are close to some point, using this FQuery (Query1):

```
SELECT page_id,name FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "45.698944", "8.462454") < 50000
```

This query returns a list of pages, but not all. For example, this query (Query2):

```
SELECT page_id,name,distance(latitude, longitude, "45.698944", "8.462454") 
FROM place
 WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "45.698944", "8.462454") < 50000 and page_id=656799421018484
```

returns:

```
{
  "data": [
{
  "page_id": "656799421018484", 
  "name": "Formatamente", 
  "distance_meters": 16006.10107316
}
  ]
}
```

My problem is that Query1 not return "Formatamente" (result of Query2) though the distance ( 16006.10107316 ) is less than 50000.

I also tried facebook graph:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?distance=50000&center=45.698944,8.462454&type=place&fields=id,name&access_token=TOKEN

but it still not returning "Formatamente".

Is there some trick to find all places around me? I will use this page_id to search all events created by this pages, or is there an easier way to find events nearest gps point?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answers

- [Facebook Graph API Get All Events For Latitude and Longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616846/facebook-graph-api-get-all-events-for-latitude-and-longitude/22630545#22630545)
- [Facebook FQL find all events that take place at a certain venue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368629/facebook-fql-find-all-events-that-take-place-at-a-certain-venue/22373119#22373119)

You're not getting the specific Page you mentioned because your're using the biggest radius possible (50000m), which yields in probably tens of thousands results (which FB is not returning completely). You can use `LIMIT start, number` in your query, but still FB won't return a high five-digit amount of results at once.