# How can I get all Facebook public events those locations ids are same to the specific given location id using Facebook Graph Api?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events, facebook-sdk-4.x

Right now, I'm getting nearby events(but not all the list) on the basis of following two graph api call:

First (getting nearby location ids):

```
search?q=*&type=place&center=lat,long&distance=50000&
limit=10000&fields=id,name
```

Second (and getting events from those location ids):

```
?ids=275177672565817&fields=events.fields(id,name,description,start_time,attending_count)
```

**But the problem is, I'm not getting all the nearby public events because it just gives me only those events which are hosted by that Facebook location page. 
I need all events either it is hosted by that location page (whose location id I've found) or by someone else who is just having same location id of his/her event.**
Can anybody tell me that is there any way to do this?

Comment: "it just gives me only those events which are hosted by that Facebook location page" - what else do you need/expect?

Comment: I need **all events** either it is hosted by that location page (whose location id  I've found) **or** by someone else who is just having same location id of his/her event.

Comment: that´s not possible afaik

Comment: oppsss! .... 
I hope there is must be a way to do this.... Anyways thanks for your answer... :)

Answer (score -1):

May be you would be able to do this, if you have created your app before April 2014? Using FQL, see the following answer

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/22373119/5212599**

Comment: I've gone through that answer but unfortunately I can't use FQL, I've created my app recently... There should be a way to do this via Graph Api... Anyways thanks for your consideration...

Comment: Yes I guess there should be the way to do it properly, B.O.L